# Unable to set connection timeout on a .NET SignalR Client HubConnection (dotnet core/signalr 2.2)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm utilizing the .NET SignalR client (SignalR Core 2.2 and DotNet Core 2.2) in an Background Service.  In my loop, I check to see if my connection object is disconnected, and if so, trigger a ConnectAsync.

I'm attempting to use SignalR for High Availability failover detection (among other things, such as config sync), so timing regarding the remote host going down or becoming unavailable is critical.

The trouble I'm having is that, on Linux, the timeouts don't seem to be responding properly.  While I have all of the configurable timeouts set to very short aggressive times in seconds, it's taking several minutes to timeout when running on Linux.  Windows doesn't seem to be having the same problem.

```
if (_connection.State != HubConnectionState.Connected) {
    _connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .ConfigureLogging(logging => {
            logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
            logging.AddConsole();
        })
        .WithUrl("https://" + settings.RemoteIP + ":" + settings.RemotePort + "/api/hub/ha", options => {
            options.Transports = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.HttpTransportType.WebSockets | Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.HttpTransportType.ServerSentEvents;
            options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(settings.RemoteJWT);         
            options.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 8);                       
        })
        .Build();

    _connection.HandshakeTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
    _connection.ServerTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
    _connection.KeepAliveInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);

    _connection.On("ExampleEvent", async () =>
    {
        await ExampleProcessor(_logger, cancellation);
    });

    await _connection.StartAsync(cancellation);
}
```

Exactly 120 seconds later after attempting to connect to a server that's unavailable, I get the following timeout error:

```
System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled. at 
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFinishSendAsyncError(Exception e, CancellationTokenSource cts) at 
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts) at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.NegotiateAsync(Uri url, HttpClient httpClient, ILogger logger) at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.GetNegotiationResponseAsync(Uri uri) at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.SelectAndStartTransport(TransferFormat transferFormat) at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartAsyncCore(TransferFormat transferFormat) at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartAsync(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HttpConnectionFactory.ConnectAsync(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HttpConnectionFactory.ConnectAsync(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsyncCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

On Windows, it's taking exactly 21 seconds to timeout, but with a different error:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at 
System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at 
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result() at 
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result() at 
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask) at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result() at 
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.AccessTokenHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at 
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts) at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.NegotiateAsync(Uri url, HttpClient httpClient, ILogger logger) at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.GetNegotiationResponseAsync(Uri uri) at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.SelectAndStartTransport(TransferFormat transferFormat) at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartAsyncCore(TransferFormat transferFormat) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartAsync(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HttpConnectionFactory.ConnectAsync(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HttpConnectionFactory.ConnectAsync(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsyncCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Am I not setting the timeouts correctly? Or is there an underlying issue with DotNet Core SignalR 2.2?

Comment: Do you mean that you set the [server timeout interval](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.client.hubconnection.servertimeout?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_SignalR_Client_HubConnection_ServerTimeout) for the connection, which does not work well while client app running on Linux?

Comment: I'm not sure which timeout setting I'm looking for for the initial ConnectAsync(); if the remote server is down and I call ConnectAsync(), i want it to time out in a matter of seconds, not minutes.  If that's the ServerTimeout setting, then yes, it's not behaving as expected, really on windows or linux - with linux being much worse.  I'm not for certain that the Negotiate timeout isn't the initial timeout, nor do I know what the CloseTimeout is for.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but I just wanted to mention that .NET Core 2.2 reached end-of-life on [December 23, 2019](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-2-2-will-reach-end-of-life-on-december-23-2019/). You may want to consider updating to Core 3.1 and see if your issue still occurs in that setting.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

My (maybe not the best) workaround was:

```
Task hubConnection = _hubConnection.StartAsync();
Task timeout = Task.Delay(ThreeSeconds);

await Task.WhenAny(hubConnection, timeout);

if (_hubConnection.State != HubConnectionState.Connected)
{
    return false;
}
```